# How to view a .DAT file?

Tags: binaryfiles

What are some strategies for opening/reading a .DAT file when it was created by an arbitrary program of which you are unaware?

Answer (score 0):

Use an hex-viewer for binary files. Pick up a free one from sourceforge.

Text editors are a bad idea due to charset encodings.